# Scatter plot of two rows of a DataFrame in Julia using Plotly

Tags: dataframe, plotly, julia

I have a dataframe and I want to create a scatter plot of columns 2:10 of the first and third rows of the data using Plotly, and also have the column names in the legend (each column in a different color).

I'm trying to do the following as a start:

```
scat = scatter(; x=Array(df[3,2:end]),
                y=Array(df[1,2:end]),
                name=names(df[3,2:end]),
                mode="markers")
plot(scat, Layout(title="Metrics", showlegend=true))
```

But I'm only getting the same color for each column in the scatter plot, and only one item in the legend called `trace 0`. How can I color each point in a different color and have it as an item in the legend named with the column name?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using Plotly in the following way in case someone is interested:

```
sc = GenericTrace[]

    for i in 2:ncol(df)
        push!(sc, scatter(x=[df[3, i]], y=[df[1, i]], mode="markers", name=names(df)[i]))
    end
plot(sc, Layout(title="Title", 
                showlegend=true))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [VegaLite](https://github.com/fredo-dedup/VegaLite.jl):

```
using VegaLite, DataFrames

df = DataFrame(x=randn(100), y=randn(100), z=randn(100))

df |> @vlplot(:point, x=:x, y=:y, color=:z)
```

[image]

Using a pre-defined colour scheme:

```
df |> @vlplot(:point, x=:x, y=:y, color={:z, scale={scheme=:plasma}})
```

[image: predefined colour scheme]

Code and images are sourced from [this julia post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-color-points-in-scatter-plot-by-value/11740/3).

More solutions and explanations can be found there as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I wasn't aware of this package, but that's good to know. I solved it using Plotly eventually so I posted my answer too.